# ruby tree class, why does it says there is 2 arguments instead of 1 in initialize?

Tags: ruby

```
class Tree
attr_accessor :children, :node_name

def initialize(tree_hash={})
    tree_hash.each do |k,v|
        @node_name = k
        @children = v.map { |k,v|   Tree.new(k,v) }
    end
end

def visit_all(&block)
    visit &block
    children.each {|c| c.visit_all &block}
end

def visit(&block)
    block.call self
end
end

ruby_tree = Tree.new({'grandpa' => {'dad' => {'child 1' => {}, 'child 2' => {} },'uncle' => {'child 3' => {}, 'child 4' => {} } } })

puts "Visiting a node"
ruby_tree.visit {|node| puts node.node_name}
puts

puts "visiting entire tree"
ruby_tree.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
```

And the error message: (I am using ruby 1.9.2)

> C:\ruby>ruby tree.rb
>
> > tree.rb:4:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
> >
> > > > ```
> > > >    from tree.rb:7:in `new'
> > > >    from tree.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
> > > >    from tree.rb:7:in `each'
> > > >    from tree.rb:7:in `map'
> > > >    from tree.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
> > > >    from tree.rb:5:in `each'
> > > >    from tree.rb:5:in `initialize'
> > > >    from tree.rb:21:in `new'
> > > >    from tree.rb:21:in `<main>'
> > > > ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 args in the line:

```
@children = v.map { |k,v|   Tree.new(k,v) }
```

Maybe you want to change `k,v` to `{k => v}` ?

```
    @children = v.map { |k,v|   Tree.new(k=>v) }
```

I think the initialisation is problematic though- what kind of tree are you implementing?

Comment: i want to implement a tree from a Hash. You can see an example in the ruby_tree variable.

Comment: I presume it's a binary tree? Most textbook implementations encapsulate the logic for nodes in a separate class. However you do it, you need some notion of enforcing a single root node and a left and right child node. Instantiating your tree with a hash will likely become quite brittle.

Comment: it's an exercise from a programming book called 7 programming languages in 7 weeks. The goal is to implement the Tree class so that it accepts a Hash as a user interface. It is implied that their will be 1 root node in the Hash. Thanks for your answer, it is working now